# How do I reactivate an event on file input cancel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have a hidden file input, and multiple clicks open up multiple file input dialogs. So I disable them temporarily like so:

on click:

```
$("#file_input").click();
$(document).off(event, #parent_click);
```

on success, on the `change` event for the file input

```
$(document).on(event, #parent_click, clickHandler);
```

HOWEVER! If the user opens up the File Dialog, and then decides to not do anything, and hits cancel, the `#parent_click` `clickHandler` can never be turned on again.

How do I rectify this?

Comment: The `change` event should also fire when the user selects 'cancel'.

Comment: @putvande That's not what I'm seeing... Wanna show an example?

Comment: I think you may have to hack it. I would try re-enabling the handler when the user clicks anywhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly got it, you can on `.change()` check for input value and if it's empty just not to fire disable

```
$('#yourInputId').change(function{
   if($('#yourInputId').val() == ''){
   //do some stuff
    } else {
   //do other stuff
   }
})
```

BTW please, could you provide some fiddle next time, if it's possible, it will be much easier to find out a solution with it.

**UPDATED** working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Goodluck/2CYv9/)**

Comment: Doesn't happen if the user cancels the File Input dialog!

Comment: @Louis93 Actually it's working, added fiddle, when you select file it disables button, when click 'Cancel' it does not.

Comment: @Good.luck That's the case where the OP says it isn't working, when you click cancel. That's because the value didn't change.

Comment: @JuanMendes ok, in this case you can use .live() , I just tell the method of doing stuff, not the complete solution.